# Emacs elisp expand-file-name behaviour on windows

Tags: emacs, elisp

I encountered strange behaviour of expand-file-name function on windows during installation of last cedet using el-get. The issue is related to generation of autoloads.

The autoload.el on last emacs 24.1.50 contains the following function:

```
(defun autoload-generated-file ()
  (expand-file-name generated-autoload-file
                ;; File-local settings of generated-autoload-file should
                ;; be interpreted relative to the file's location,
                ;; of course.
                (if (not (local-variable-p 'generated-autoload-file))
                    (expand-file-name "lisp" source-directory))))
```

In my case generated-autoload-file is:

```
"/home/ngulyamov/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet/lisp/cedet/srecode/loaddefs.el"
```

as I have $HOME$ environment variable pointed to C:/home/ngulyamov. In this case above function returns:

```
"d:/home/ngulyamov/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet/lisp/cedet/srecode/loaddefs.el"
```

due to source-directory contains:

```
"d:/devel/emacs/emacs-bzr/trunk_jenkins/".
```

As you can see it changes drive letter from C: to D:.
At the same time on emacs 23.3 this function returns semi-correct value as source-directory contains value:

```
"c:/Users/Sean/Downloads/emacs-23.3/".
```

According to expand-file-name function description:

*(expand-file-name NAME &optional DEFAULT-DIRECTORY)*

Convert filename NAME to absolute, and canonicalize it.
Second arg DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is directory to start with if NAME is relative
**(does not start with slash or tilde)**; if DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is nil or missing,
the current buffer's value of `default-directory' is used.

The paths on Windows never start from slash or tilde.

Now my questions:
1. Does expand-file-name function behaviour correct on Windows?
2. Why source-directory contains value of developers paths?

Could we consider expand-file-name as buggy on windows? Or it is just wrongly used in autoload.el?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was that first path supposed to start with `c:` ?

Comment: @phils
Hi, no, it doesn't start with C: but everything works pretty good:

`C:\home\ngulyamov>set HOME
HOME=C:\home\ngulyamov


C:\home\ngulyamov>env | grep HOME
HOME=/home/ngulyamov

C:\home\ngulyamov>ls /home/ngulyamov
... file list ....`

Comment: This is obviously some kind of Windows shell I've never seen before, if it uses forward slashes, and accepts `ls` as a command. (Is that Windows 7?)

Comment: @phils No, it is just a normal cmd.exe, I have cygwin installed and its bin directory in my PATH. And it is Windows XP.

Comment: Is Emacs configured to integrate with Cygwin? If so, that could be a relevant point.

Comment: @phils No, I didn't do anything special to integrate cygwin with emacs. Moreover, el-get to install packages most of the time runs another instance of emacs with -q parameter which eliminates all local configurations.

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest trying along those lines, then, would be removing the Cygwin bin directory from PATH to verify that Emacs wasn't using something in Cygwin in preference to something Windows-native with the same name. If the error occurred during el-get's installation though, you might need to remove and reinstall to actually test it? Might be worth a try if nothing else works.

Comment: `expand-file-name` is *probably* fine, as DOS/Windows has always let you use absolute paths without a drive letter (it assumes the 'current' drive letter), so what you're seeing seems to tie in with that. I suspect your question #2 is the important one. In the default cedet libraries in Emacs, the `generated-autoload-file` seems always to be set as a file-local variable, and is typically simply "loaddefs.el", relative to that file. Establishing where that drive-letter-less absolute path originates from would seem to be key?

Comment: @phils Hi, thank you for all your tips. Please check my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured out the reason. The issue is coming from Makefile of cedet which uses $(abspath) functionality of make 3.8. The cygwin version of make in this case returns UNIX way of path, i.e. /home/ngulyamov/... which then replaces by source-directory root in autoload by d:/home/ngulyamov/.... The GnuWin32 version of make works correctly but by strange reason I have the following issue:

```
C:\home\ngulyamov\.emacs.d\el-get\cedet>\gnuwin32\bin\make all
Removing loaddefs.el files from subprojects.
Generating autoloads.
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/home/ngulyamov/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet/lisp/cedet'
    > autoloads
Wrote C:/home/ngulyamov/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet/lisp/cedet/loaddefs.el
Loading vc-bzr...
Generating autoloads for C:/home/ngulyamov/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet/lisp/cedet/cedet-android.el...
Memory exhausted--use C-x s then exit and restart Emacs
make[1]: *** [autoloads] Error 127
```

So dirty fix is specifying source-directory in autoload.el itself like:

```
(setq-default source-directory "C:/home/ngulyamov/.emacs.d/")
```

Anyway, why source-directory is pointing to developer's computer path is remaining open.